# Search engine question

Tags: views, search, database

I have a site that has over 18,000 data items in a catalog. I am using Drupal 7 and the latest Views module to display the data. The data items contain an auto make, model, year, cv axle. My search query needs to be able to search this catalog in the following matter: If the EU click in an input box for "make," they can put in the search term (e.g. Ford) and all Ford models pull up. In addition, there is another search field next to the "Make" field for "Model" and another one for "Year." I want Drupal to add all the search terms together to alter the view. Right now, If the user types in one term and searches, it works; however, if the EU types in another term in the "Model" field say, the view that outputs will only include the last term searched.
For example, I type in "Ford," and all Fords come up; if I add a term to the "Year" field (e.g. 1999), all 1999 autos come up, not just the Ford models of that year.

How do I create a search engine that spans terms across multiple fields (Make+Model+Year: OR however many search term the EU wishes to include) to filter what is output through Views?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

www.sutrack.biz=> cv axle catalog link

Answer (score 2):

You might considder using the [search api](http://drupal.org/project/search_api) module. It allows you to do full text search on the index you setup, it has support for facets integrates with Solr and a lot of other nice things. I can recommend it for some easy and powerful search. It also integrates with Views allowing you to easily customize search results.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal there are different ways to integrate Apache Solr to your system. I have chosen to use Search API as it has already built integration with views and you can create different types of  indexes for our site.It shows how to add filters to your view, restricting what content is displayed.

Comment: Please do not add a signature or blatant advertising in your answers.  See the [FAQ](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures)

Answer (score 0):

In your view definition / Contextual filters / More have you enabled 'Allow multiple filter values to work together'?